# Typescript resolve types for private scoped package

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings, tsconfig

I have a package hosted in an Azure Artifacts npm feed, scoped to @company, e.g. to add the package we use `yarn add @company/package`. This package is a typescript project, that when compiled also includes type files.

When using it, the exposed types are not being resolved, and compilation fails.

Example of build:

- build

  - index.js
  - index.d.ts

Example package.json

```
{
  "name": "@company/package",
  "version": "0.0.5",
  "module": "./build/index.js",
  "types": "./build/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf ./build && tsc -p tsconfig.json --noEmit false",
    "prepublish": "npm run build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  },
  "files": [
    "build/"
  ]
}
```

At the same level as the package.json, there is a `.npmrc` file, and a `tsconfig.json` file.

.npmrc

```
@company:registry=https://company.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/company-npm/npm/registry/
                        
always-auth=true
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "ES2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "preserveConstEnums": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "outDir": "build/esm",
    "declaration": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts",
    "src/__mocks__/Api.ts"
  ]
}
```

We can install public npmjs packages and @types with no problem, and the `@company/package` also works (an @company folder appears in node_modules, and include the package code, including the `index.d.ts` file).

When referencing the code from our package (which happens to be react components), it shows errors stating `JSX element type 'Button' does not have any construct or call signatures`, which is a result of the typescript typings not resolving properly.

We have tried altering the tsconfig.json of the project using the scoped package, so that the type roots also include the @company scope, e.g.

```
"typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "node_modules/@company"
],
```

We have also tried various iterations of installing the types (which haven't been manually published, I just thought it might work as part of the npm publish) `yarn add -D @company/@types/package` `@types/@company@package` but both commands return the following error;

```
yarn add v1.22.0
warning package.json: No license field
warning project@0.0.0: No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/types/company-react-components.git
Directory: /mnt/c/Users/user/source/repos/project/src/project.Ui
Output:
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

How do you properly reference types published as part of a scoped package? If it is being referenced properly, why are the types not resolving?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I just spent half a day banging my head agaist the wall before getting it to work.

You need to name your package `@myorg/mypackage` to get npm to use the scope `@myorg:registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/...` that you have defined in `.npmrc`.

To make TypeScript happy, and to not have to manually tweak the typeRoots, you can install the package, and alias it back into `@types/myorg__mypackage` naming:

`npm i @types/myorg__mypackage@npm:@myorg/mypackage@latest --save-dev`

You'd probably want to document that in the readme, as it's not at all intuitive for the poor souls that want to consume the package.

Comment: I no longer have a way of confirming this for it's intended context, but I know others have poked around at this, so hopefully it helps them. Thanks!